# Programmatically convert infopath 2010 forms to pdf using Infopath object model

Tags: infopath

I have infopath 2010 forms published to sharepoint 2010 forms library. I want to provide an option ( webpart with a button) in the forms library to export the published form to PDF. Is there a way to accomplish this using Infopath 2010 forms servies object model.

*Is there any OOTB feature in Infopath Forms Services Object model that will convert forms to PDF*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704378/how-to-export-an-infopath-form-as-a-pdf-from-within-a-winform-hosted-formcontrol might shed some light

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the reply. I'm experimenting with Muhimbi pdf convert for sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

As infopath is offered as one or more COM objects with an extensive API, you may be able to find a way to convert an infopath form to pdf (losing the form input capabilities).
From an MSDN search, I get one fellows answer :"A low tech way to convert an Infopath file to pdf is to copy & paste the form into MS Word, "save as" html then use Adobe Acrobat to convert the new file to a pdf."

Answer (score 0):

check out my codeplex project [IP2HTML](http://ip2html.codeplex.com/) which allows you to convert the for to HTML (you can convert the HTML to PDF using any 3rd party tool) without installing MS Office.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Will have a look at it.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for the reply. I'm experimenting with Muhimbi pdf converter for sharepoint.